# "ERROR: 409 Document already exists" when adding new documents into Google Firestore database

Tags: python, firebase, flask, google-cloud-firestore

To give you an idea of the greater context of this issue; I am building a web app where users can create lists inside boards to organise their work, in python, using flask and firebase. Much like many other todo apps. However, my issue is localised in the code I have provided below.

```
@boards.route("/board/create", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def create_board():

    # Ensure title exists.
    if not request.form.get("title"):
        log.error("Title is empty.")
        return redirect("/profile")
    
    title = request.form.get("title")
    
    try:
        ref = firebase_database.collection("users").document(session["localId"]).collection("boards")
    
        # Add board to database.
        ref.add({
            "timestamp": firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP, 
            "title": title,
            "description": ""
        })
    
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(f"Error connecting to database. {e}")
        return redirect("/profile")
    
    return redirect("/profile")
```

The intention of this code is to retrieve the user input, named "title", and add a new document with a unique ID under the sub-collection "boards".

I chose to use the function "add" because it does exactly what I described. It creates a document with a unique identifier, I have linked the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). However, whenever I call this function I am returned the following error:

> ERROR: Error connecting to database. 409 Document already exists: .../users/sycvmE14lIVjDr6nHzwhy18wxNm2/boards/CqnIB5oN7SQjou5tXASs

The explanation for this error is that there is already a document with the same name/key. This is strange because the add() function is supposed to create a document with a unique key. There of course is a chance this could happen, but it is so improbable it shouldn't be a concern. I have re-run this code over and over and it continues to produce the same error.

I attempted the following code as a work around (replacing the add() function with the set() function and inserting the document() function at the end of the initialisation of the reference, which is supposed to do the same thing). Interestingly, I am not returned an error, but instead if there is already a document created in the database, it will re-write that document with the same unique identifier it produced previously, over and over. Occasionally it will produce a document with a different key, but this is rare and I haven't found a way to re-create this intentionally.

```
try:
    ref = firebase_database.collection("users").document(session["localId"]).collection("boards").document()

    # Add board to database.
    ref.set({
        "timestamp": firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP, 
        "title": title,
        "description": ""
    })
```

I additionally attempted to write my own function to implement the same functionality of creating a document with a unique identifier.

```
def generate_random_id(size : int = 20):
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

```
try:
    ref = firebase_database.collection("users").document(session["localId"]).collection("boards").document(generate_random_id())
    
    # Add board to database.
    ref.set({
        "timestamp": firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
        "title": title,
        "description": ""
    })
```

However, when using this function, the same effect, that had happened previously where it re-wrote the data is produced. This blows my mind, suggesting it is something to do with my code instead of with firebase. It is as if the function to create a unique key is only run once at runtime and stored in a variable to be used when needed, but this is not the case.

If it helps I have also inserted the html which calls this method below.

```
<form action="/board/create" method="post">
    <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Title">
    <button>Add</button>
</form>
```

If there is anything else which would be helpful to include, please do let me know.

I would really appreciate any help at all, I am seriously lost.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to read this,
Seb.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the document that you are adding the subcollection to?

If I had to guess, the issue would be the `ref` variable that you are creating.

```py
ref = firebase_database.collection("users").document(session["localId"]).collection("boards")
```

I'll usually ensure that the document is created first, then add a document to my subcollection

```py
userDoc = get_or_create_user_doc(session["local_id"])
userDoc.collection("boards").add({"data": "here"})
```

Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. However, I add the user to database on creation as below.

`firebase_database.collection("users").document(user["localId"]).set({
            "displayName": firebase_auth.get_account_info(user["idToken"])["users"][0]["displayName"] 
        })`

I then create the 'boards' collection when creating the first board in the create_board() function. The list then immediately follows.

I apologise if I am misunderstanding what you are saying, but I think this is what I am already doing.